# how to correctly write a protobuf message in text format to a file

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

My question is how to correctly write a protobuf message in text format to a file. In the program below I create a `NetParameter` object which is a message
field in message field in caffe.proto.

When I call `print()` and `PrintToString()` they return failure.

I can print the mesaage on the console with `printf("%s", data.c_str());` but notting is written to file?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h>
#include <google/protobuf/text_format.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream> // NOLINT(readability/streams)
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "caffe.pb.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <caffe/caffe.hpp>

using namespace std;
using google::protobuf::Message;
using google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream;
using google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream;
using google::protobuf::io::FileInputStream;
using google::protobuf::io::FileOutputStream;
using google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyInputStream;
using google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream;
using google::protobuf::TextFormat;


int main()
{
    caffe::NetParameter param;
    const char *filename = "./test.prototxt";

    int fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    if (fd == -1)
        cout << "File not found: " << filename;

    google::protobuf::io::FileOutputStream* output = new google::protobuf::io::FileOutputStream(fd);

    param.set_name("AlexNet");
    param.add_input_dim(0);
    param.add_input_dim(1);
    param.add_input_dim(2);
    param.set_input_dim(0, 3);
    param.set_input_dim(1, 3);
    param.set_input_dim(2, 3);

    std::string data;
    bool success = google::protobuf::TextFormat::PrintToString(param, &data);
    std::cout << "bool is " << success << std::endl;
    printf("%s", data.c_str());

    bool success1 = google::protobuf::TextFormat::Print(param, output);
    std::cout << "bool is " << success << std::endl;



    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `output.Close()` or `output.Flush()` before `close(fd)`.  Also, your second success line should reference `success1` instead of `success`

Comment: @JamesPoag `Output.Flush()` was it thanks. Can't understand why success is 1 though and not zero.

Comment: Streams write to memory and then flush to disk when the memory buffer is full or when the file is closed.  The Print was sucessful, your `output` object just had the text in memory.